# Как добавить finish?

Tags: java, android

Есть такой метод

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_progress_show) {
            progress_menu_item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);
            if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1)
            {
                frag2.reloadWebView(); // Call method
            }
            if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==2)
            {
                frag3.reloadWebView1(); // Call method
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progress_menu_item.setActionView(null);
                }
            }, 5000);
            return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

хочу совместить с этим

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

если нажата `R.id.home` выполнялся финиш а если не нажата то 1 условие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if(id == android.R.id.home){
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            else if (id == R.id.action_progress_show) {
                progress_menu_item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_layout);
                if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==1)
                {
                    frag2.reloadWebView(); // Call method
                }
                if(viewPager.getCurrentItem()==2)
                {
                    frag3.reloadWebView1(); // Call method
                }
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progress_menu_item.setActionView(null);
                    }
                }, 5000);
                return true;

            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

Comment: спасибо тебе добрый